# Blurred image in Windows Phone application

Tags: wpf, image, windows-phone-7, scale

I am writing program for Windows Phone 7.1 and using component Image, I stretch image in it - and its get blurry. I`ve studied such issues - it seems like UseLayoutRounding="True" should help, but it didnt help for me.
Here is the code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" UseLayoutRounding="True" Background="Transparent">
    <controls:Panorama x:Name="mainPanorama" Title="life rpg" SelectionChanged="Panorama_SelectionChanged_1">
        <controls:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Imgs/bg.jpg"/>
        </controls:Panorama.Background>
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="main" Tag="main" >
            <StackPanel Name="mainPanel">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="165" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165" Source="picture.png" Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
                    <Image Name="swordImg"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Source="Imgs/swords/swordLVL1.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                    <Image Name="armorImg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"  Source="Imgs/armors/armorLVL1.png" Stretch="Uniform"  />
                    <Image Name="shieldImg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Source="Imgs/shields/shieldLVL1.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />                        
                </StackPanel>
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
```

Comment: Try playing with the `RenderOptions` on the image you may be able to find a nice setting e.g. `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"`, and not sure if `SnapToDevicePixels` is avaliable on Phone 7, but if it is try `SnapToDevicePixels="True"`

Comment: What is the image resolution?

Comment: image resolution is 25x25 i try to scale it x2, x4, x6

Comment: RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" and SnapToDevicePixels="True" are both not available on Phone 7

Answer (score 0):

If the quality of an image is important when displayed at a large size then you have 2 options.

1. Start with a large image. Bitmap images will suffer distortion when made larger. This will be amplified depending on the compression/quality setting used within a JPEG file.
2. Use an image in a vector format.

Answer (score 0):

Given the low resolution of your image (given that it is raster format and not vector), you cannot upscale it without losing quality. No rendering options will help you here.

A 25x25 image for a `Panorama` background is definitely not enough quality-wise.